Formation of Ketal with monohydric alcohol
Do ketones react with monohyric alcohol to form ketals?
Some books state "Ketones do not readily react with monohydric alcohols"
While some form ketals with monohydric alcohols.
Which one is true?

Ketones react with monohydric alcohols under anhydrous acid/Lewis acid conditions to form ketals.  Formation of a dimethyl ketal is a widely used protection strategy for ketones and aldehydes https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(Vollhardt_and_Schore)/17%3A_Aldehydes_and_Ketones_-_The_Carbonyl_Group/17.08%3A_Acetals__as_Protecting_Groups

The reference posted by waylander doesn't seem to have the answer .

Could you please explain how the link doesn't answer your question? Perhaps, you can add your thinking as well.

@Emma  try this one then  https://ncstate.pressbooks.pub/organicchem/chapter/nucleophilic-addition-of-alcohols-acetal-formation-3/
